# how to define jquery function in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

i was working on angularjs. And now i recently started working on angular 4. I want to know how the below jquery function can be written in angular 4. I had tried many examples but still not working.

```
(function( $ ){
    $.hcDs = function(){
            var baseConfig = {
                      "chart": {
                        "type": "",
                      },
                      "credits": {
                        "enabled": false
                      },
                }
```

Comment: What's your goal? You can use some jquery in Angular, but its not a recommended way to do things. Maybe this config is something you could store in an Angular Service instead?

Comment: put the above code inside script tags in the index.html file. Also link the jquery cdn above that. Again as @bgraham said, direct manipulation of DOM elements using jQuery is not recommended.